# Mqtt publishing the messages to localhost. And telegraf is monitoring localhost but cannot send it to the influxdb. what might be going wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, influxdb, telegraf

Here,
if telegraf to influxdb connection is successful because when i restart the telegraf it creates the db which i mentioned in the config file. But the messages which are publihsed by mqtt are not recieved by the telegraf I even tried to put it into file but it’s empty.
so something is wrong.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
import  json

influxclient = InfluxDBClient(host='localhost', port=8086)
# This is the Publisher

dict_msg={"temperature":"20.5"}
msg = json.dumps(dict_msg)

MQTT_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
MQTT_PORT = 1883
MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL = 45
MQTT_TOPIC = "sensors"

count = 0

# Define on_publish event function 
def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
print("Message Published..")


# Initiate MQTT Client
mqttc = mqtt.Client()

mqttc.on_publish = on_publish

# Connect with MQTT Broker
mqttc.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT, MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL)

x = 0
while x <= 100000:
    # Publish message to MQTT Broker
    mqttc.publish(MQTT_TOPIC,msg)
    # influx_line_protocol = ("published,counts" = count)
    # print(count)
    x += 1

mqttc.loop(30)
# Disconnect from MQTT_Broker
mqttc.disconnect()`
```

Here's the telegraf config and my mqtt publisher code which is given.
I want my published messages to be stored in influxdb.

telegraf says connected as given below but its not sending any messages from publisher.
freezes here

```
2019-02-07T11:02:18Z I! [agent] Config: Interval:10s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"shekhar-Inspiron-3441", Flush Interval:10s
2019-02-07T11:02:18Z I! [inputs.mqtt_consumer] Connected [tcp://127.0.0.1:1883]
```

and mqtt config has

```
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
## MQTT broker URLs to be used. The format should be 
scheme://host:port,
## schema can be tcp, ssl, or ws.
servers = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"]

## Topics to subscribe to
topics = [
  "telegraf/sensors/#",
   ]
data_format = "influx"
```

tried with json also.
no luck.

any help appreciated.

Comment: You are publishing on topic `sensors` and subscribing to `telegraph/sensors/#`

Comment: subcription has to be done to sensors/# only then???

Comment: To just match what you are publishing, subscribing to just `sensors` would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were 2 things wrong:

1. You didn’t configure your InfluxDB output in telegraf.conf
2. Your temperature reading is a string, not a number type

I’ve provided a working example of using the MQTT plugin for you here:

https://github.com/rawkode/influxdb-examples/tree/master/telegraf/mqtt

PS: Cross-post by Shekhar. Copying my answer here, with the demo; in-case someone else runs into a similiar problem.

https://community.influxdata.com/t/mqtt-publishing-the-messages-but-telegraf-cannot-send-it-to-the-influxdb/8462/7